# How does CAP theorem relate to multi-master replication?

Tags: database, multi-master-replication

How do these two things relate and what kind of properties does an asynchronous multi-master database system have in the context of the CAP theorem?

Answer (score 2):

first, this theorem about multi-master databases (in terms of theorem "distributed system"), so the relation is straightforward

next issue: if you have asynchronous system, this mean that at some particular moment data in one node is not the same as in another node, so this system is not "consistent", as system is not consistent and some node fails - data from this node are totally lost, and there is no copy in other nodes

so theory says: "system **cannot** be consistent and available and partition tolerant at the same time" - asynchronous multi-master database provide only 1 guarantee, so theorem is correct